# update existed contact with multi number android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am using this code to update number for existing contact on android:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation
                .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?"
                                + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + "=?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId),
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE })
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, mobileNumber);
ops.add(builder.build());
```

I want to add another number to this contact with Type = `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK` not clear old number.

How to do this with `ContentProviderOperation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have found solution

```
builder = ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawcontactId)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, String.valueOf(type));
            ops.add(builder.build());
```